# Jersey web service work on Localhost but not on Web service

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am new to web technology, I have some doubts, i have problem to setup Jersey web service into my Web server. I am using Eclipse IDE, I dont know how Eclipse compiles my jersey web service code but it works on my local machin but same project won't work.
I get 404 error on server.

I create POM.xml to add dependency for file upload but technically i dont know that it compiles my project or not.

here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>WebService</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.example.webservice</param-value>
   </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
 <servlet>
   <display-name>Apache-Axis Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!-- JNDI -->
 <resource-ref>
<description>DB Connection</description>
 <res-ref-name>jdbc/KernelDataSource</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

and POM.XML is

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey</groupId>
<artifactId>JAXRS-HelloWorld</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>
```